# Compilation error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

class cName
{
public:
    cName();
    void fName(){};
};

#define LNA_FUNCTION(className, funcName) \
 static LNA_FUNCTION<className> funcName##className##Func(#className, #funcName, className :: funcName)

LNA_FUNCTION(cName, fName);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   

}
```

Can anyone please why this error is shown when compiled in VS 2008?

> Compilation error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The macro expands to `static LNA_FUNCTION<cName> `... which is a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing all your code, you have probably not defined a template class called `LNA_FUNCTION`. Have you `#include`'d all of your dependencies?

As a sidenote, I would strongly advise against writing a class and then defining a preprocessor macro with the same name. It will probably not do what you want it to do.